# Changing eye icon when clicking on it with using toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I am new in html and UI side. I am trying to add an eye icon to show and hide password to my page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#icon-click").click(function() {

    $("#icon").toggleClass('fas fa-eye');

    var input = $("#pass");

    if (input.attr("type") == "text") {
      input.attr("type", "password");
    } else {
      input.attr("type", "text");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="form-group input-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0" placeholder="Şifre" id="pass" />
  <a href="#" class="text-dark" id="icon-click">
    <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

When the page opens, keep the eye icon off. When I click on it, I want it to open and show the password. When the page is opened, the eye icon is turned off (first pic). When I click on it, it also shows the password but the icon disappears(second). I just couldn't fix this. I thing the problem is in `.toggleClass('fas fa-eye')` part. When I change the .toogleClass part as `.toggleClass('fa-eye')`, the icon remains as in the first picture, it does not change.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image: icon disappeared]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove and add `fa-eye-slash` and `fa-eye` on each click depending on what existed before. You can do it like so :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#icon-click").click(function() {

    var className = $("#icon").attr('class');
    className = className.indexOf('slash') !== -1 ? 'fa fa-eye' : 'fa fa-eye-slash'

    $("#icon").attr('class', className);
    var input = $("#pass");

    if (input.attr("type") == "text") {
      input.attr("type", "password");
    } else {
      input.attr("type", "text");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0" placeholder="Şifre" id="pass" />
  <a href="#" class="text-dark" id="icon-click">
    <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

because the class `fa fa-eye-slah` not removed when `icon-click` get click

add this to check condition class at id `icon`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#icon-click").click(function() {

                if ($("#icon").hasClass("fa fa-eye-slash")) {  //check the class
                    $("#icon").removeClass( "fa fa-eye-slash" ).addClass( "fas fa-eye" );
                }else if($("#icon").hasClass("fas fa-eye")){
                    $("#icon").removeClass( "fas fa-eye " ).addClass( "fa fa-eye-slash" );
                }

                
                var input = $("#pass");

                if (input.attr("type") == "text") {
                    input.attr("type", "password");
                } else {
                    input.attr("type", "text");
                }
            });

        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
<body>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0" placeholder="Şifre" id="pass" />
        <a href="#" class="text-dark" id="icon-click">
            <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding this javascript to the *if* statement:

```
e.target.classList.remove('fa-eye');
e.target.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
```

and the opposite for the *else* statement.

**Test:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#icon-click").click(function(e) {          // capture the event e here
      var input = $("#pass");

      if (input.attr("type") == "text") {
        input.attr("type", "password");
        e.target.classList.remove('fa-eye');    // e.target is what is clicked (icon)
        e.target.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
      } else {
        input.attr("type", "text");
        e.target.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
        e.target.classList.add('fa-eye');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="form-group input-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0" placeholder="Şifre" id="pass" />
  <a href="#" class="text-dark" id="icon-click">
    <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```